# Cómo ocultar un icono solo con css en ReactJS si está vacío

Tags: css, reactjs

Mi consulta es breve, necesito saber cómo ocultar un icono que se está importando desde otro componente con CSS...

Este es el icono a ocultar:

```
 <i className={`${this.props.Icon}`}>
```

Esto es lo que intenté:

```
.Contenedor i:empty { display: none; }
```

También intenté esto:

```
.Componente i[class]:empty { display: none; }
```

Ninguna de las combinaciones funcionó...

**Nota:** El icono sí se muestra cuando se lo llama desde otro componente pero cuando no se ingresa un ícono no se oculta el padding del icono.

**Por ejemplo:** Para un botón dentro de un ícono que tenga texto, se ven ambos textos pero al quitar el contenido, se mantiene el padding.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y por que no lo ocultas con react? validas tu prop, y si no tiene nada entonces no muestras el icono

Comment: Puedes intentar usando el selector `i:not([class]):empty` (sin attributo `class` y vacio)

Comment: Como dice @Isaac, ¿por qué no lo haces con React? Podría ser así: `{this.props.Icon && <i className={this.props.Icon}></i>}`.